# Bypassing the vote correction filter

Tags: discussion

#### Backstory:

A few days ago (after getting some users angry), I got a downvote on a post of mine, which was 5 months inactive. And on two other old posts in the following days ([my reputation tab](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/143228/rudolf-l-jel%C3%ADnek?tab=reputation)). I doubt this is a coincidence, but I don't want and will not investigate further on this, after all, it's only 3 votes.

#### Real question:

The story above, though it's of (absolutely) no importance, sparked up a few hypothetical questions:

- This has a key feature: All recently voted-on posts were voted on only once recently. Can the vote filter be bypassed by up- or down- voting on a single user's posts across a long period of time? Like, 60 votes in a month?
- What should a user do if he sees many of his posts, active or not, voted on in a row?
- Is a user that serial votes another user's votes across a long period of time traceable?

Comment: @Vemonus The backstory isn't imortant, it's not the reason I'm asking this here, it's just a thing that happened. 3 votes (not 2, don't know if you oversaw one) are not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! We'd still catch the perp.

The tools mods have to detect patterns of abuse (and I'm presuming the SE staff has even better ones) don't limit themselves to any sort of temporal scope. 60 downvotes is 60 downvotes, regardless of when they took place.

If you suspect a targeted campaign, by all means, raise a custom flag voicing your concerns, but the system is pretty good at handling these problems as is.